# Incompatible jest and react-native-paper libraries

Tags: android, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-paper

I have a react native expo project which uses react-native-paper. When I tried to add unit testing with Jest I encountered a problem. Jest tests don't work with the configuration provided by expo docs. I have the following error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

This is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "~48.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-wheel-picker-expo": "^0.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I was able to fix this issue by adding a babel.config.js file with some configurations but this broke react-native-paper giving an error with MaterialCommunityIcons.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', { loose: true }],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

So after deleting the babel.config.js I'm back were I started trying to make both react-native-paper and jest work.

Comment: any progress on this? I have a similar problem